# how to re-create virtual box bridge interface for wlan in linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, network-interface, wlan

I want to have a virtual interface connected to the wlan interface which is acting as a bridge by having two mac address and ip address on the same network with the same credentials just like the one in virtual box, where no matter which wifi is connected to, the virtual machine connects to the same network without credentials and uses the same physical wlan interface. how can I achieve this ?

Comment: To have a bridge working with Wifi on the client side rather than the access point side requires 4 addresses mode. The usual setup on all Access Points (ie: the home router, not the computer) is to use the standard 3 addresses mode. So to have something working everywhere requires to reconfigure the Access Point everywhere to work with 4A mode. 1/ very few can do this 2/ you must have total control of them 3/ this defeats the goal of having things work by default without effort